# Problems with livequery and rte on firefox 3.5.2

Tags: jquery, rte, livequery

i been using the following code for some time now and it has worked ok on ie6-8 and firefox 3.

```
$("#article").livequery(function () {
    $("#article").rte({
        cssUrl: "css/rte.css",
        mediaUrl: "css/rte/",
        listenToClass: "send"});
    });
```

but now that i have upgraded to firefox 3.5.2 it enters an infinite loop adding rte boxes. could that be realted to the code itself or an incompatibility with new firefox??

Comment: I don't think Firefox 5 is considered stable yet -- that might be a factor.

Comment: sorry about the version typo =p

Comment: What event you want livequery to handle exactly?

Comment: You might want to look into jQuery live(), it has become part of core since 1.4, so plugins for event delegation (like livequery and listen) are not really needed anymore -- http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Jquery live has replaced livequery for quite some time now. Since version 1.4.

In the newest version of jquery 1.7+ .on() is now the recommended function for event delegation.

I'm not sure what event you are trying to bind to in your example, but I'd take a look at .on, or .live() or .delegate() if you are using an earlier version.

Comment: just realized this post is quite old as well, just showed up in the "unanswered questions" section